Unexpected token '?' when run send.js or receive.js from rabbitMQ tutorial
I tried to learn RabbitMQ, and I follow the Streams example  with NodeJS. I copied the source code of send.js and receive.js, but when i run "npm run send" or "npm run receive" it give me this error

rabbitmq-stream-node-tutorial@1.0.0 send
node send.js
/home/italspazio-zorin/Scrivania/rabbitmq/node_modules/rabbitmq-stream-js-client/dist/client.js:43
this.connection = connection ?? this.getLocatorConnection();
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:85:18)
at Object. (/home/italspazio-zorin/Scrivania/rabbitmq/node_modules/rabbitmq-stream-js-client/dist/index.js:18:14)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)

I'm on Linux (Zorin OS) with rabbitmq installed and the server running, I can access to the control panel with http://localhost:15672/ address.

What's your node version?

?? is the (nullish coalescing operator)[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing] and is available from Node 14 which was released in April 2020.

Ok, I solved updating NodeJS, I thought I had the last version

Your node version does not support coalescing operator (??)
You need to Update to Node 16 or above
Check your version
node -v

install nvm
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.2/install.sh | bash

Terminal Restart
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh

install and use node 16
nvm install 16
nvm use 16

